# Pickup or microphone or hybrid?

Tags: recording, homerecording

I am a fingerstyle guitarist learning how to record quality sound by studying from other recordings. In this video, I am guessing the dude is recording directly from the pickup attached to his guitar and not the microphone. What do you think? Also what kind of post processing is done?

Edit: I understand the audio and video are recorded separately. I want to get deeper into the audio recording part of this shoot. Is it possible to figure out what device (pickup/microphone) is used for recording just by listening? What kind of post processing is done?

Comment: Wondered why the strings were oscillating wildly - it's tuned down a tone. Unless there's a mic attached to the guitar, then it's likely a pup. Were there a mic close to the guitar, his movements would show in volume differences, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Tried both methods myself. Pickups are good for live shows because microphones can add feedback. But if you're using headphones when you record in a studio a microphone will be a lot more quality than a pickup on an acoustic/classical guitar. People usually use a condenser mic + computer + audio interface that supplies phantom power to the mic to record instruments. Or sometimes condenser mics directly to usb (ie usb microphone). I especially like field microphones (zoom, tascam, etc) that have multiple condenser mics within them because you can bring them anywhere and they have an audio interface built in. [Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=An-PQEAxsF8) using a zoom h4 to record both guitar and vocals. As mentioned in the answers the video you showed was most likely recorded in the studio first.

Comment: As i mentioned above, I understand the audio is recorded in studio first. I want to get deeper into that audio recording part of this shot. Is it possible to figure out what device (pickup/microphone) is used for recording? What kind of post processing is done?

Comment: @LuvAgarwal I don't think there's a way to know exactly what type of mic was used. but as mentioned probably condenser. he also has delay effects and reverb going on too.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty certain he isn't recording directly at all, the video was shot to playback of a studio recording.  There's reverb, delay, possibly some double-tracking...   The recording could have made with a mic (or mics) or a pickup.  I suspect mics.

Comment: I understand that video is shot separately. I am trying to understand just the audio bit of it.